# Combining GET and POST in Sinatra (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, rest, post, heroku, sinatra

I am trying to make a RESTful api and have some function which needs credentials. For example say I'm writing a function which finds all nearby places within a certain radius, but only authorised users can use it.

One way to do it is to send it all using GET like so:
`http://myapi.heroku.com/getNearbyPlaces?lon=12.343523&lat=56.123533&radius=30&username=john&password=blabla123`

but obviously that's the worst possible way to do it.

Is it possible to instead move the username and password fields and embed them as POST variables over SSL, so the URL will only look like so:
`https://myapi.heroku.com/getNearbyPlaces?lon=12.343523&lat=56.123533&radius=30`

and the credentials will be sent encrypted.

How would I then in Sinatra and Ruby properly get at the GET and POST variables? Is this The Right Way To Do It? If not why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really trying to create a restful API instead if some URL endpoints which happen to speak some HTTP dialect, you should stick to GET. It's even again in your path, so you seem to be pretty sure it's a get.

Instead of trying to hide the username and password in `GET` or `POST` parameters, you should instead use [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which was invented especially for that purpose and is universally available in clients (and is available using convenience methods in Sinatra).

Also, if you are trying to use REST, you should embrace the concept of resources and resoiurce collections (which is implied by the R and E of REST). So you have a single URL like `http://myapi.heroku.com/NearbyPlaces`. If you `GET` there, you gather information about that resource, if you `POST`, you create a new resource, if you `PUT` yopu update n existing resource and if you `DELETE`, well, you delete it. What you should do before is th structure your object space into these resources and design your API around it.

Possibly, you could have a resource collection at `http://myapi.heroku.com/places`. Each place as a resource has a unique URL like `http://myapi.heroku.com/places/123`. New polaces can be created by `POST`ing to http://myapi.heroku.com/places. And nearby places could be gathered by `GET`ing `http://myapi.heroku.com/places/nearby?lon=12.343523&lat=56.123533&radius=30`. hat call could return an Array or URLs to nearby places, e.g.

```
[
    "http://myapi.heroku.com/places/123",
    "http://myapi.heroku.com/places/17",
    "http://myapi.heroku.com/places/42"
]
```

If you want to be truly discoverable, you might also embrace [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) which constraints REST smentics in a way to allows API clients to "browse" through the API as a user with a browser would do. To allow this, you use Hyperlink inside your API which point to other resources, kind of like in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

The params that are part of the url (namely `lon`, `lat` and `radius`) are known as query parameters, the user and password information that you want to send in your form are known as form parameters. In Sinatra both of these type of parameters are made available in the `params` hash of a controller.

So in Sinatra you would be able to access your `lon` parameter as `params[:lon]` and the `user` parameter as `params[:user]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using basic or digest authentication and a plain GET request. In other words, your request should be "GET /places?lat=x&lon=x&radius=x" and you should let HTTP handle the authentication. If I understand your situation correctly, this is the ideal approach and will certainly be the most RESTful solution.

As an aside, your URI could be improved. Having verbs ("get") and query-like adjectives ("nearby") in your resource names is not really appropriate. In general, resources should be nouns (ie. "places", "person", "books"). See the example request I wrote above; "get" is redundant because you are using a GET request and "nearby" is redundant because you are already querying by location.